# SVG and Input tags get nudged when height is about 10px

Tags: html, svg

With an SVG within a div with specified height, if the height is about 10px or less, the SVG element is moved down.

Similar thing happens with input tags.

Example comparing 10px height to 20px height:

```html
<h1>SVG</h1>
<div style="height:10px; background-color:red">
  <svg style="height:10px;">
    <rect x=0 y=0 width=10 height=10></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
<div style="height:20px" ></div>
<div style="height:20px; background-color:yellow">
  <svg style="height:20px;">
    <rect x=0 y=0 width=20 height=20></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
<h1>Input</h1>
<div style="height:10px; background-color:red">
  <input type="text" style="height:10px;padding:0;" value="x" >
</div>
<div style="height:20px" ></div>
<div style="height:20px; background-color:yellow">
  <input type="text" style="height:20px;padding:0;" value="x" >
</div>
```

This happens in Chrome 76, FF 68 and Edge 42.

Is this a bug, or there a logical reason for this I haven't figured out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `display: block` to the svg element. By default elements such as svg and images have `display: inline` and are positioned on the text baseline.

You could also add `line-height: 10px` to parent div of first svg to see the difference

Comment: nitpick: default browser style for <img> and <svg> is `display: inline` not `inline-block`. But since these are [inline-replaced-elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width), they do have some special treatments wrt to width and height.

Comment: I like nitpicks! Learned something today, so thanks you!